# Meteor: onReady data subscription

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to implement the following pattern in [meteor](/questions/tagged/meteor): the server has some data sets, which are published to client as smaller chunks, i.e. the client subscribes to a subset of data.

```
//server
Meteor.publish("dataWindow", function(){ 
   //publish a subset
   return Data.find({},{limit:100};});
});

//client
Meteor.subscribe("dataWindow", function onReady(){
//do stuff with dataWindow, but this doesn't work
//display(dataWindow)
});
```

However with this implementation on the client the dataWindow is empty.

A couple of things I don't understand:

- Where do I put the collection definitions in this case?
- Does the client have a collection dataWindow?
- How do I refer to dataWindow inside `onReady` ([formerly `onComplete`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/273#issuecomment-9191316))?
- What is [iron-router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router), and what does have to do with the onReady function call?

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend reading the [meteor book](https://www.discovermeteor.com/) to better understand the basic concepts of meteor. I'd also suggest having a look at the [publish and subscribe](http://docs.meteor.com/#publishandsubscribe) section of the docs. Without a basic understanding of publish and subscribe it may be hard for you to understand the answers to your questions but I'll give it a shot:

#### Where do I put the collection definitions in this case?

Because they are shared between the server and the client, put the definitions in a directory directly underneath your application directory, e.g. `/collections/posts.js`.

```
Posts = new Meteor.Collection("posts");
```

I'm going to assume for the rest of this answer that your collection is `Posts`, because `Data` is a little too generic. So your publish function could look like:

```
Meteor.publish("postsForDashboard", function(){ 
   return Posts.find({}, {limit: 100});
});
```

And your subscribe could look like:

```
Meteor.subscribe("postsForDashboard");
```

#### Does the client have a collection dataWindow?

No. The name of the publish function (in our example `postsForDashboard`) is just an identifier. The documents will be published to the client using the same collection they were found in (`Posts`). This also answers your first question.

#### How do I refer to dataWindow inside onReady?

You don't. It's just an identifier used to select the publish function. In our example you could do:

```
console.log(Posts.find().fetch());
```

Note that it's pretty unusual to directly use the callback for a subscribe. The typical use case is to simply subscribe to the data and then use it in a template.

#### What is iron-router, and what does have to do with the onReady function call?

Iron router is a client-side router which is useful when you want to have more than one route in your app (e.g. /dashboard, /posts, /posts/abc123/edit). A nice feature of iron-router is that it can wait for your data to be ready and display templates accordingly. So for example, while your posts were syncing it could show a spinner, and when they were done it could show a template displaying them. Again, you do not need to directly access the subscribe's callback in order to make this happen.

---

I hope this was helpful, but I'd strongly recommend reading through the above sources to gain a better understanding of how all this works.